# array buffer not working with webgl

Tags: javascript, webgl, arraybuffer

I am currently trying to use an arraybuffer with views, to combine 3 float32 (x,y,z) and 4 uint8 (r,g,b,a) into a single data stream that I can pass to my web gl application.

Problem is the when I use the array buffer nothing works, code as follows:

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(nbrOfVertices * 16);
var positionView = new DataView(buffer);   

for (var j = 0; j < nbrOfVertices; j++)
{
    positionView.setFloat32((j*16),meshVertexPositions[(j*7)]);
    positionView.setFloat32((j*16)+4,meshVertexPositions[(j*7)+1]);
    positionView.setFloat32((j*16)+8,meshVertexPositions[(j*7)+2]); 
}
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,buffer,gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

I know all the other code is correct, because when I use this instead it works:

```
var buffer = new Float32Array(nbrOfVertices * 4);

for (var j = 0; j < nbrOfVertices; j++)
{
    buffer[(j*4)] = meshVertexPositions[(j*7)];
    buffer[(j*4)+1] = meshVertexPositions[(j*7)+1];
    buffer[(j*4)+2] = meshVertexPositions[(j*7)+2];
}
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,buffer,gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

Any idea why my arraybuffer code (first example) isn't working?
Just for clarification, when I say it doesn't work, I mean nothing renders, although I don't see any errors when I run it (in chrome developer console or in webgl inspector)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use a `DataView` for this. You'd use multiple views on the same buffer like this

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(nbrOfVertices * 16);
var floatView = new Float32Array(buffer);
var uint8View = new Uint8Array(buffer);

for (var j = 0; j < nbrOfVertices; ++j) {
  var floatVertexOffset = j * 4;
  floatView[floatVertexOffset + 0] = meshVertexPositions[?? + 0];
  floatView[floatVertexOffset + 1] = meshVertexPositions[?? + 1];
  floatView[floatVertexOffset + 2] = meshVertexPositions[?? + 2];

  var uint8ColorOffset = j * 16 + 12;
  unit8View[uint8ColorOffset + 0] = meshVertexColors[?? + 0];
  unit8View[uint8ColorOffset + 1] = meshVertexColors[?? + 1];
  unit8View[uint8ColorOffset + 2] = meshVertexColors[?? + 2];
  unit8View[uint8ColorOffset + 3] = meshVertexColors[?? + 3];
}
```

The reason you would not use a `DataView` is because you want the native float and RGBA formats for GPU data. `DataView` is for reading/writing data in a specific endian format regardless of the native platform's endianess.

In other words, if you use `DataView` you'll end up uploading the wrong type of data to the GPU. You use `DataView` to read into native format or convert native data to specific binary formats.

Comment: Thanks a million man, i've been stuck on this for like 2 days already

Comment: You can use a DataView if you specify the endianness. I had to use it in a cross platform project and it worked right after I specified the endianness.